# Akka.net and IIS Thread pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, akka.net

I would like to know how Akka.net will work with IIS and asp.net, because Asp.net creates thread pool for the request/Response .

If the threads are used by Actor system then we are taking some threads out for the Request to be served which will have a negative influence in the scalability.

If Akka.net is not using the threads how it will create a concurrent work to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Akka.net uses special Dispatcher abstraction to control code execution inside actors. If you want a dedicated thread pool for your actors, you may use ForkJoinDispatcher implementation. Here is a doc for Dispatchers - https://getakka.net/articles/actors/dispatchers.html

Also, because you're running your Akka.net instance inside ASP.net and IIS, you need to know that application pool where your application lives, could be started and stopped at any time. So you better not do any heavy-lifting inside IIS-hosted Akka.net instance - https://getakka.net/articles/intro/use-case-and-deployment-scenarios.html#aspnet

Comment: Thaks @usein . Between my question was bit different. I don't want new thread pool. Instead I want to know how it is currently done .